# couldn't able to write a File in FTP from Mulesoft Cloudhub

Tags: java, ftp, mulesoft, mule4

Getting the below error while trying to connect to FTP from Cloudhub.

**Found exception trying to obtain path /XX/XXXX/XXXXXXX_20200721151112.dat.
Ftp reply code: 150. Ftp reply string: 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list**

Below are my FTP configuration  and logs of FTP.

```
<ftp:config name="FTP_Config-yrbk-deposits-ftp" 
    doc:name="FTP Config" doc:id="79692e72-be49-428b-87cd-2522c3ca0aa6" >
    <ftp:connection 
        workingDir="${yrbk-deposits-ftp.directory}" 
        host="${yrbk-deposits-ftp.host}" 
        port="${yrbk-deposits-ftp.port}" 
        username="${yrbk-deposits-ftp.user}" 
        password="${secure::yrbk-deposits-ftp.password}" 
        controlEncoding="UTF-8" 
        transferMode="ASCII" 
        connectionTimeout="5">
            <reconnection >
                <reconnect frequency="5000" count="3" />
            </reconnection>
            <pooling-profile minEvictionMillis="60000" evictionCheckIntervalMillis="60000" />
    </ftp:connection>
</ftp:config>
```

[image: FTP logs]

Answer (score 0):

The error 150 indicates that a PASV (passive) command was missed. Try setting the passive="true" attribute in the FTP connector configuration.